# In a RESTful API, is generating a resource using PUT and an empty body semantically valid?

Tags: api, rest

I have a requirement to generate a resource. This process has side effects so can’t be modelled as a GET. The ID is known, so PUT would work well. The resource is small, however the properties are not known at request time. Hence the verb generated, not created.

Would this be considered semantically valid and RESTful?

Update:

An example would be the resource /randomnumbers. The implementation I’m proposing would see a PUT /randomnumbers/123 with no body create a resource with a property called randomNumber. The value would be a random number generated by the server. The value would never change on subsequent PUTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is generating a resource using PUT and an empty body semantically valid?

Yes, absolutely

```
PUT /example.txt HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
```

Is precisely how you would communicate to the server that you want an empty file available with the identifier `/example.txt`.

Expressed this way, the [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) request describes an upsert - if the resource doesn't exist, create it; if the resource does exist, then replace the current representation with the representation provided in the request body (which in this case, is empty).

If you wanted the request to specifically mean "create"; that is to say, if the semantics of the request are that an existing representation for the resource should be left unchanged, then you would communicate that using the [pre-condition header fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3).

> You should use POST instead of PUT to generate resources

This is not correct.  See [Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST only becomes an issue when it is used in a situation for which some other method is ideally suited: e.g., retrieval of information that should be a representation of some resource (GET), complete replacement of a representation (PUT), or any of the other standardized methods that tell intermediaries something more valuable than “this may change something.”

One of the the things that using PUT tells intermediaries is that the semantics of the request are [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), which means that they can do clever things like automatically resend a request if no response is received in a timely fashion.

POST is sometimes a more appropriate choice, the key consideration is this one:

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.

In a case where you are going to let the server choose the uri of the new resource, then POST rather than PUT is going to be the appropriate choice.

> Just to give more information on my use case, perhaps a good example would be if, besides the ID, the resource had one property called randomNumber. I want the server to generate that property, not provide it in the body - the body is completely empty. The number is then stored at the ID specified. The number won’t change on subsequent PUTs - it’s idempotent. So PUT randomnumbers/123 with an empty body would generate a resource with the property set to for example randomNumber: 719526

That makes me a bit twitchy, but I think it is OK.  The key idea is that HTTP defines the semantics of the messages, but it doesn't constrain implementation.  There's no guarantee, for example, that the server's copy of the resource will end up looking like the copy provided in the request.

You do have to take some care in preparing the response to ensure that you don't *imply* that the representation provided in the request is accepted "as is".  (See [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4))

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just to give more information on my use case, perhaps a good example would be if, besides the ID, the resource had one property called randomNumber. I want the server to generate that property, not provide it in the body - the body is completely empty. The number is then stored at the ID specified. The number won’t change on subsequent PUTs - it’s idempotent. 

So PUT randomnumbers/123 with an empty body would generate a resource with the property set to for example randomNumber: 719526

Answer (score 0):

You should **use POST instead of PUT** to generate resources, even when the id is known in advance. The difference is the expected idempotence: when calling POST again with the same id it should result in an error, as the resouce has already been created, whereas multiple PUT requests with the same id will just update the resource.
See: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

An empty body is unusual, but valid for both POST and PUT. 
See: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2010JulSep/0273.html

Hint: if your REST API does not support it, it will usually accept a zero-length body, such as an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I’d always believed the defining feature of a PUT is knowledge of the identifier, so that’s good to know. I can implement the endpoint to be idempotent, I’m guessing PUT would be fine then? From a client POV it would be easier as well as it means one less call of checking if it exists before calling.